# How to auto replay video in Android Studio VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-videoview

I know this is a very stupid question, but what is the simplest way to add auto replay to a video in an Android app? I've been looking around StackOverFlow but didn't find anything that would work. Here's my MainActivity.java, if it helps:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.gotem);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code before calling `video.start()`

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

This waits for the `MediaPlayer` to be prepared and then loops the content of the `MediaPlayer` since `VideoView` uses `MediaPlayer` internally.